Is the NET 8 Blazor web app template flawed?
Is the template project which gets data for the weather page flawed in the sense that data is retrieved in the OnInitializedAsync() method?

In the real world, you likely want pre-rendering to occur
You want some sort of "loading..." indicator while you obtain your data
And assume getting the data is a "long running" process

The template project will get the data twice, if you refresh the weather page (or request it directly from the browser), rather than using the interactive (enhanced) navigation from another page.
It seems a much better way to handle this situation is to do something like the following (I am using a weatherService to get the WeatherForecast data):
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        forecasts = await weatherService.GetWeather();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

This seems to be the simplest way to guarantee that the app is not accessing the data twice.
Here's another alternative (and it is arguably better, according to some people)
[CascadingParameter]
HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (HttpContext == null) // i.e. this is not a pre-render situation, and will be the final call to this method for this request
    {
       forecasts = await weatherService.GetWeather();
    }
}

In any case, the example project should not be obtaining data twice.
Am I missing something?

The template isn't flawed. It's not written to handle every case though, it's written to be a starting point. I suspect the misunderstanding starts from In the real world, you likely want pre-rendering to occur. That's not the general case, nor is it as clear as you think. Landing pages should get pre-rendered. Pages showing live data though, maybe not. Pre-rendering is an advanced feature in all SPA frameworks. If you want live data the first time you load the page, you may not benefit from prerendering. Many of the components can be prerendered, but the grid requires fresh data

In the real world you don't want to load data that the user may not want. You may want them to fill some search properties first, so you don't have to load 1000 rows only to display 25 of them. In that case, you shouldn't load the grid data upon initialization at all. You'd load the data when the user clicks on eg Search. If you use query parameters, you'd also load the date in OnParametersSetAsync. This would allow you to navigate to a page with preset filters

Seems you have found out that pre-rendering does not trigger OnAfterRender. There are more direct (better) ways to control this.

And what is the use of pre-rendering w/o data?

Two important points:

OnAfterRender{Async} is a UI event. It's raised by the Renderer when the browser signals that a UI update has completed. It isn't part of the component lifecycle methods. That's an extremely important distinction. The calls to StateHasChanged in the component lifecycle may ultimately trigger OnAfterRender{Async}, but that's just a consequence of an action. There's no direct linkage, and therefore no control over when OnAfterRender{Async} is executed by the synchronisation context.

The Blazor Synchronisation Context prioritizes delegates posted to it's queue over UI event delegates. It effectively has two queues: the Post queue and the UI queue. The lifecycle code is posted to the Post queue, OnAfterRender{Async} is queued on the UI event queue.


Components need to implement a handler for IHandleAfterRender interface.  ComponentBase does so.
Add the following code to any component:
@implements IHandleAfterRender
 //...
    Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

OnAfterRender[Async] will no longer run.  The code above overrides the ComponentBase implementation and short-circuits it.
The implications:

You don't control how long awaiters wait [or even if they wait at all] : you have no control on when OnAfterRender{Async} runs.

Different await periods may cause the event to run at a different point in the lifecycle.  The lifecycle methods almost certainly mutate the component state, and that state will be different at the two execution points.  See the detail in the referenced article to see this in action.

Changing state in OnAfterRender{Async} means you need to execute one more call to StateHasChanged to update the UI to the current component state. Why not just execute the code in the lifecycle methods?


Pre-Rendering is basically a con trick to make the user believe the page has loaded quicker than it has.
If you're not interesting in the con:

Turn off pre-rendering.
Detect Pre-Rendering on page-by-page or globally and show simple loading page.

What's OnAfterRender for?  Running JS interop.
So is it really bad?  Probably not.  You may get some unpredictable intermediate results in certain circumstances.  You do more renders that you need to (and can get into render loops).
I'd describe it as a code smell.  Could be implemented more efficiently.  I've seen comments from other long term Blazor coders that do the same as me: very rarely use OnAfterRender{Async}.
See this answer for how to implement a splash screen:
Blazor .Net 8 splash screen
This content has been copied from this discussion of mine - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/OnAfterRender.html
PS - It looks like detecting pre-rendering will be built in to ComponentBase in the next Blazor release.

Please elaborate on why the reason I proposed it is flawed is not the right reason. Also, the accepted "answer" provided in the link you provided is incorrect. It says, among other things, "OnInitializedAsync is only called once (per component/page)" -- this is demonstrably false. The answer you provided in the link is not well-explained or backed-up. Give a solid reason why data (such as the weather data in the example) should not be done in OnAfterRender. And then show a good example of where it should go. Anyway--thanks for your reply.

The other discussion link you provided does have some good info--and a reasonable alternative of determining if you are prerendering or not -- and fetching data accordingly.

See my updated answer. The original was a short answer written late last night!

"It isn't part of the component lifecycle methods". This sentence is confusing me. Well it's listed under the lifecycle methods in the docs.

@jeb - It's talked about, but I don't think it's actually stated as such.  Can you reference exactly where?  Because if it does it needs changing!   it normally says something like  .. await DOM update ....  Components are a very complex subject.  They can also be very confusing at times even with a deep understanding of how they work.

sure here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@Jeb - agree that on reading this you would understand that OnAfterRender{Async} is part of the lifecycle, and in a sense it is.  However, it happens as a consequence of calling StateHasChanged, not an intrinsic part of executing `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}'.
