How to prevent the business logic present inside the Blazor SSR component's OnInitialized method from executing twice?
I understand that a Blazor SSR component's OnInitialized method executes twice if pre-rendering is enabled. I have written the business logic, for e.g., loading all the products from the database, inside the OnInitialized method. How do I prevent the business logic from executing twice? Do I have to keep track of it using a local variable such as IsInitialized = false, and then set it to true once the business logic executes. Does Blazor have a built-in way for detecting this? Or should I move the business logic to a different lifecycle method?
[Update 9/23] Adding the code here for more clarity (implemented @Rena 's 4th answer). Removed all the extraneous code. All components derive from BaseComponent, in which I want to find out the signed-in user. Hence I call the method to get the usercontext in the OnInitialized method, but I want that logic to execute only once. Currently both GetUserContextFromAuthenticationState and GetProductsListFromDatabase are being executed twice. isInitialized is always false.
In the App.razor, I don't specify the render mode, so the application starts in Static Server Render mode. And in the BaseComponent, I specify the Interactive Server Render mode.
BaseComponent.razor
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@code {
    private bool isInitialized = false;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            var user = GetUserContextFromAuthenticationState();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}

Products.razor
@inherits BaseComponent
@code {
    private bool isInitialized = false;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            var products = GetProductsListFromDatabase();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}

[Update 9/24] Detecting pre-render using the IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext works (@Rena answer 2). Marking that as answer.
Though I would like to know why the above code doesn't work. Are the blazor components instantiated twice? That could be the reason why isInitialized is always false. Should I ask this as a separate question? I have spent so much time trying to understand blazor component lifecycle, and still don't get it.

The answer to the following question should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78723051/is-the-net-8-blazor-web-app-template-flawed.  Note that OnAfterRenderAsync should not be used.  The answer explains why.

There are several ways we can achieve:
1.As the official document said:

To prevent developer code in OnInitializedAsync from running twice
when prerendering, see the Stateful reconnection after prerendering section.

2.You can use the IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted property to check whether the application is pre-rendering or not.
@code{
    [Inject]
    protected IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var isPreRendering = !this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted;
    
        if (!isPreRendering)
        {
            //call your service...
        }
            
    }
}

The HttpContextAccessor service should be registered by calling the AddHttpContextAccessor method in the Program.cs.
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

3.Consider using OnAfterRenderAsync if you need to perform logic that should only run once after the component is fully rendered. However, be cautious since it runs after every render.
@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //call your service here
        }
    }
}


Thank @Rena. I tried 4) above, but isInitialized is always false, even if I set it to true. So the logic always runs twice. Any idea what could be happening. Should isInitialized be static?

Hi @Shankar, have your tried other ways I shared? For the 4) not working, i think you can share a minimal example code with us.

Hi @Rena, added the code above.

Hi @Shankar, You could only use the build-in method to judge the prerender after testing your code. Please try my answer, i have shared three ways.

Hi @Rena - see the following answer as to why you should not use OnAfterRender{Async} as a possible solution to perceived pre-render issues.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78723051/is-the-net-8-blazor-web-app-template-flawed.  You can also capture the cascaded HttpContext [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }and test for null in any component.

Hi @Rena, looks like you removed your 4th answer, can you please keep it there for completeness sake? I also would like to know why 4th answer did not work. Are the blazor components instantiated twice? That's the only explanation I could come up with for isInitialized being always false.

Hi @Rena, answer 2 works. I'm using it.
